# devpi upload error: no commands supplied to setup.py

Tags: python, devpi

When trying to upload to `devpi-4.1.0`, the same error occurs no matter what options I choose. The workaround is to build package and upload it as a file, but I'm not able to upload any docs.

```
(tstenv) [root@master workspace]# devpi upload --formats sdist
detected devpi:upload section in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myproject-deploy-release/workspace/setup.cfg
using workdir /tmp/devpi29
pre-build: cleaning /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myproject-deploy-release/workspace/dist
-->  /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myproject-deploy-release/workspace$ tstenv/bin/python setup.py sdist 
warning: sdist: standard file not found: should have one of README, README.rst, README.txt

built: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myproject-deploy-release/workspace/dist/myproject-1.0.0.dev0.tar.gz [SDIST] 2642.98kb
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myproject-deploy-release/workspace/tstenv/bin/devpi", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myproject-deploy-release/workspace/tstenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/devpi/main.py", line 30, in main
    return method(hub, hub.args)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myproject-deploy-release/workspace/tstenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/devpi/upload.py", line 48, in main
    name_version = exported.setup_name_and_version()
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myproject-deploy-release/workspace/tstenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/devpi/upload.py", line 311, in setup_name_and_version
    report=False).splitlines()[-1].strip()
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myproject-deploy-release/workspace/tstenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/devpi/main.py", line 214, in popen_output
    return check_output(args, cwd=str(cwd))
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myproject-deploy-release/workspace/tstenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/devpi_common/proc.py", line 18, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myproject-deploy-release/workspace/tstenv/bin/python', '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myproject-deploy-release/workspace/setup.py', '--name']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

---

As requested in the answers, here is the output of `devpi sdist upload`:

```
(tstenv) [root@master workspace]# devpi sdist upload
usage: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myproject-deploy-release/workspace/tstenv/bin/devpi
   [-h] [--version] [--debug] [-y] [-v] [--clientdir DIR]
   {quickstart,use,getjson,patchjson,list,remove,user,login,logoff,index,upload,test,push,install,refresh}
   ...
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myproject-deploy-release/workspace/tstenv/bin/devpi: error: argument command: invalid choice: 'sdist' (choose from 'quickstart', 'use', 'getjson', 'patchjson', 'list', 'remove', 'user', 'login', 'logoff', 'index', 'upload', 'test', 'push', 'install', 'refresh')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to documentation](http://doc.devpi.net/latest/quickstart-releaseprocess.html#devpi-upload-uploading-one-or-more-packages) it's just `devpi upload`.

Comment: Nope, and according to `devpi upload` usage, it shouldn't work. Nevertheless, I updated the question with the command output.

Comment: Thanks. The output is showing that it's running 'setup.py --name' without a command so the error is correct. If just 'devpi upload' does not work it would be a bug in devpi or your setup.py script. Can verify by calling setup.py sdist upload directly.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the `setup.py upload` suggestion! It indeed works, so I will file a bug shortly.